# Conflict between TikZ and university thesis class file

Tags: tikz-pgf, document-classes, incompatibility

When compiling a document using my university's thesis class file and the TikZ package I receive an error message (missing number, treated as zero). Would someone know how I can solve this problem?

```
\documentclass[phd,bottom,nosig]{usbthesis}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Test 1-2-3
\end{document}
```

The class file can be found here:

http://graduate.physics.sunysb.edu/faq/thesis_template/usbthesis.cls

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Error message goes away if you add `\RequirePackage{tikz}` _before_ the `\documentclass`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In `usbthesis.cls` change the line:

```
\renewcommand{\year}[1]{\newcommand{\@year}{#1}}
```

to,

```
\newcommand{\myyear}[1]{\newcommand{\@year}{#1}}
```

and use `\myyear` rather than `\year` in your document.

It looks like `pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex` uses `\year` to generate a random seed.  Since the class redefines `\year` before it's use in that file, you're getting the error.

Comment: How did you discover this?

Comment: @sigur TexnicCenter will take you to the line where an error was produced.  That opened up the `pgfmathfunctions` file and showed that the error was produced in the line: `\xdef\pgfmath@rnd@z{\the\c@pgfmath@counta}`.  Since none of that was likely to have been clobbered by the class, I checked the line above, which used `\year` and that seemed a likely candidate :)

Answer (score 14):

The class file badly redefines `\year`, which is a TeX macro for the current year, and is used by `pgf` to set a random number seed when it loads.

Changing the order of loading the packages, as Peter Grill suggests, will fix the MWE but other issues may still be present.

In the following, use `\setyear` instead of `\year` from the class:

```
\let\oldyear\year
\documentclass[phd,bottom,nosig]{usbthesis}
\let\setyear\year
\let\year\oldyear
\errorcontextlines=\maxdimen
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Test 1-2-3
\end{document}
```

You should probably also do something similar for `\month`.

If you are able to tell the University to fix their class file, then Scott H.'s answer is preferable (with a `\mymonth` as well).

Comment: @hjms  I'll leave my answer up, but this is the better solution since you don't have to muck around with the class file.

Answer (score 14):

If you don't want to change the `.cls` file you could simply add

```
\RequirePackage{tikz}
```

before the `\documentclass`.

### Code:

```
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\documentclass[phd,bottom,nosig]{usbthesis}
%\usepackage{tikz}% no longer needed.
\begin{document}
Test 1-2-3
\end{document}
```