# What does the @ symbol sign do in Latex?

Tags: macros

The document class my Uni provides has a bunch of lines that appear to define macros with "@" in the name, like this:

```
\newcommand{\uni@title}{}
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\renewcommand{\uni@title}{#1}}

\newcommand{\uni@year}{}
\renewcommand{\year}[1]{\renewcommand{\uni@year}{#1}}
```

But when I tried defining macros with a @ in the name it didn't work:

```
%this works
\newcommand{\helloworld}[1]{Hello #1 !}
\hello{everyone}

%this gives tons of error messages and
%prints weird stuff to the document:
\newcommand{\hello@world}[1]{Hello #1 !}
\hello@world{everyone}
```

What are they `@` signs doing in my document class file then?

---

Anyway, the reason I am asking all of this is that the `\year` macro is [conflicting with a system package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91262/conflict-between-tikz-and-university-thesis-class-file). I am thinking about renaming all the commands to something more namespaced and less ambiguous. Is camelCase the only way to go? I tried `uni@year` and `uni_year` and I'm getting the impression that macro names can only be alphanumeric...

Comment: Please report the conflict to the maintainer of your universities class.

Comment: TeX uses the @ symbol for internal macros that the user is not normally supposed to use directly. If you want to access a class or package macro with an @ in it, surround that section with  `\makeatletter` (which means, read @ as a letter) and `\makeatother` (which means, read @ as a reserved character) so that TeX will read the @ symbol properly.

Comment: @AndrewCashner: so for "external" macros, the only way to avoid conflicts would be to define camelcased macros like `UNIyear`, right?

Comment: Yes, use case to distinguish separate parts of the macro name, and use roman numerals if necessary for numbers.