# University Thesis Class File Conflict With Natbib Package

Tags: natbib, incompatibility

I have a university thesis class file at
https://github.com/uclathes/uclathes

When I'm trying to use the natbib package, compiling error with pdflatex shows

```
LaTeX Error: Environment thebibliography undefined.
l.1063 \renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
```

Minimum code:

```
\documentclass[PhD]{uclathes}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
Test 1-2-3 \citet{austin2002simplescalar}
\bibliography{bib_references}
\bibliographystyle {plainnat}
\end{document}
```

bib_references.bib file

```
@article{austin2002simplescalar,
  title={SimpleScalar: An infrastructure for computer system modeling},
  author={Austin, Todd and Larson, Eric and Ernst, Dan},
  journal={Computer},
  volume={35},
  number={2},
  pages={59--67},
  year={2002},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
```

I found a similar question here
[Conflict between TikZ and university thesis class file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91262/conflict-between-tikz-and-university-thesis-class-file/91263)

I tried to change the variable name thebibliography defined in the thesis class file to be a different one, but the error still shows.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post a minimal document that has this issue. According to the class file the `thebibliography` environment **is** defined

Comment: Oh my, the `uclathes.cls` file apparently dates back to 1995... And the link to other question concerns a totally different class ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Unfortunately it is...  If I'm not using natbib, but the most common \cite, everything works fine. It is even good when I'm using biblatex, but not natbib

Comment: Your minimal code works for me -- there's no error message

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I should include a little more. Now when I compile with pdflatex+bibtex+pdflatex+pdflatex, the error shows at the second 'pdflatex'

Comment: Yes, it throws an error `\newblock` being undefined.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'm compiling with Texlive, so maybe the error message is a little different from yours. I noticed that \newblock is defined both in natbib.sty and uclathes.cls.

Comment: I am using TL 2016 on Linux, with daily updates