# Tikz and EPL format incompatible

Tags: tikz-pgf

When I use epl2 format http://www.epletters.net/authors/epl-macro-template/ and the tikz package it causes a compilation error an appears an empty page at the begining of the document.

```
\documentclass[doublecol]{epl2} 
\usepackage{tikz}
% or \documentclass[page-classic]{epl2} for one column style

\title{Title of the paper}
\shorttitle{Title} %Insert here a short version of the title if it exceeds 70 characters

\author{F. Author\inst{1,2} \and S. Author\inst{1} \and T. Author\inst{2}}
\shortauthor{F. Author \etal}

\institute{                    
  \inst{1} First Institute - Address\\
  \inst{2} Second Institute - Address
}
\pacs{nn.mm.xx}{First pacs description}
\pacs{nn.mm.xx}{Second pacs description}
\pacs{nn.mm.xx}{Third pacs description}


\abstract{
Abstract of the paper.}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the text of the error?

Comment: [Possible duplicate?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91262/82917) Different class but same problem.