# Compiler-Error: Missing number, Undefined Control Sequence, Missing \begin{document}

Tags: compiling

I am using the IEEE Access template and i get the following errors:

1. Missing number
2. Undefined Control Sequence
3. Missing \begin{document}

---

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess} 
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} 
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{textcomp} \def\BibTeX{{\rm
B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{blindtext} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs} \usepackage{graphics}

\usepackage{caption,setspace} \usepackage{tikz}

% draw a circle with a number 
\newcommand*\mycirc[1]{%  
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(C.base)]
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=0.25pt, minimum size=11pt](C) {\footnotesize#1};   \end{tikzpicture}}

% checkmark and X symbol 
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont 
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%

% set graphics path 
\graphicspath{{./Material/}}


\clubpenalty = 10000     
\widowpenalty = 10000          



\captionsetup{font={sf,small,stretch=0.80},labelfont={bf,color=accessblue}}

    \begin{document} [...]
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Hi, welcome. Does the code look exactly like what you see now, after my edit? There are some linebreaks missing, before `\newcommand` and `\usepackage{pifont}`, the URL should be commented`.

Comment: Seems that class is incompatible with `tikz`. Edit: by the way, as `ieeeaccess` is not a standard class, a link to it (http://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-article/use-authoring-tools-and-ieee-article-templates/ieee-article-templates/templates-ieee-access/) would have been a useful addition to the question.

Comment: Haha, I have a line `% https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters#Other_Symbols` right next to my `\usepackage{pifont}` to have a quick access to the list of glyphs included in pifont. I guess the link in your preamble is there for a similar reason, isn't it?

Comment: @thymaro Or it might just be copied from Werner's answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42620/

Comment: @TorbjørnT. saved. It's much more beautiful than what I had in the link.

Comment: Came across this again, the cause is the same thing as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91262/conflict-between-tikz-and-university-thesis-class-file, the class redefines `\year` in a way that is incompatible with TikZ.