# How to use tcolorbox with ieeeaccess.cls?

Tags: tcolorbox

Whenever I try to use tcolorbox with ieeeaccess.cls, the main title and section topics disappear!! anyone know what the problem is? Thank you in advance.

Here, without using tcolorbox.
[image: without using tcolorbox]

Here, using tcolorbox.
[image: using tcolorbox]
Here is an example code.

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{flexisym} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
%\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox} %when this package is used, the main title and section topics disappear.

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
  T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}
\history{Date of publication xxxx 00, 0000, date of current version xxxx 00, 0000.}
\doi{10.1109/ACCESS.2017.DOI}


\title{Preparation of Papers for IEEE ACCESS}


\begin{abstract}
abstract.
\end{abstract}


\titlepgskip=-15pt

\maketitle


\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:introduction}
\PARstart{T}{his} first section

\subsection{subsection}
subsection


\section{Second Section}
This is the second section
\section{Third Section}
This is the third section


\EOD

\end{document}
```

Please note:
1- Unfortunately, ieeeaccess.cls requires IEEEtran.cls class, so to compile this example you need IEEEtran.cls to be in the same directory with ieeeaccess.cls. You will get both classes when you download the official LaTeX template for IEEE Access.

2- Another option is; you can down the official LaTeX template for IEEE Access from the official website, then add the package  \usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox} to see the problem.

Click [HERE](https://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-article/use-authoring-tools-and-ieee-article-templates/ieee-article-templates/templates-ieee-access/) for the official website for IEEE Access LaTeX template

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You will have much better chances to get a quick and good reply if you provide us with a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), i.e. a compilable document that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}` and illustrates the problem.

Comment: Hello marmot, I have added a minimal working example. Thank you

Comment: @M.Al Your document is not compileable, it is missing `\begin{document}` and even if you add it, it still doesn't compile!

Comment: Hello  AndréC, Thank you for drawing my attention to `\begin{document}` . I have updated the post. The code is working now. Please have a look.

Comment: It seems to be a conflict with the `\year` command redefined in `ieeeaccess.cls`. (tcolorbox loads tikz which then uses `\year` for its random seed.)? Similar symptom as [Conflict between TikZ and university thesis class file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91263/117534). I'm not familiar enough with the class nor tikz to suggest a workaround..

Comment: Hello Troy, the problem is solved, it is the same solution of [tikz package causing error in IEEE access template] (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440422/tikz-package-causing-error-in-ieee-access-template). Thank you

Comment: The problem has the same solution of [tikz package causing error in IEEE access template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440422/tikz-package-causing-error-in-ieee-access-template). Thanks for everyone tried to help.

Comment: @M.Al +1 for your problem and its solution. I never received your message because you forgot the `at` sign in front of my nickname, see how to answer someone here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work