# How to change the document class to tikz stand alone?

Tags: tikz-pgf, document-classes, standalone

How to change the document class `\documentclass[english]{IEEEtran}` to `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}`. And I still can get the same output figure.

```
   \documentclass{ieeeaccess}
               \usepackage{tabularx}
         \usepackage{booktabs}
         \usepackage{longtable}
          \usepackage{multirow}
      \usepackage{colortbl}
           \usepackage{caption}
       \usepackage{hhline}
        \usepackage{tabularx,colortbl}
       \usepackage{mathtools}
        \usepackage{eqnarray,amsmath}
        \usepackage{amsmath}
        \usepackage{hyperref} % for autoref
     \usepackage{cite}
         \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
       \usepackage{algorithmic}
        \usepackage{graphicx}
      \usepackage{enumitem}
        \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}


   \usepackage{array}
     \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
        \newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
        \usepackage{booktabs}
          \usepackage{makecell}
           \usepackage{tikz}
            \usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

   \usepackage{array}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
   \newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
   \usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
  \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

   \begin{document}
\begin{table*}

    \begin{minipage}{0.2\linewidth}
        \centering
        \caption{First Table}
        \label{tab:first_table}
        \tikz[remember picture]{\node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt](A){%contents
        \begin{tabular}{cCc}
            \toprule
            \textbf{Start} & \makecell{\textbf{Interval}\\ \textbf{Time}} 
            & \textbf{Disease} 
            \\
            \midrule
            A & 483 & B \\
            A & 848 & C  \\
            A & 121 & Zone 4  \\
            B & 13 & C \\

            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}}}   
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{.2\linewidth}

        \caption{Second Table}
        \label{tab:second_table}
        \tikz[remember picture]{\node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt](B){%contents
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            \toprule
            \textbf{Start} & \makecell{\textbf{Interval}\\ \textbf{Time}} 
            & \textbf{Disease} 
            \\
            \midrule
            A & 483 & B \\
            A & 848 & C  \\
            A & 121 & Zone 4  \\
            B & 13 & C \\

            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}}}   
    \end{minipage}\hfill
       \begin{minipage}{.2\linewidth}

        \caption{Second Table}
        \label{tab:second_table}
        \tikz[remember picture]{\node[inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt](C){%contents
        \begin{tabular}{ccc}
            \toprule
            \textbf{Start} & \makecell{\textbf{Interval}\\ \textbf{Time}} 
            & \textbf{Disease} 
            \\
            \midrule
            A & 483 & B \\
            A & 848 & C  \\
            A & 121 & Zone 4  \\
            . & . & . \\
             . & . & .  \\
            B & 13 & C \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}}}   
    \end{minipage}

\end{table*}



      \end{document}
```

Comment: One question first. Why do you want to change to `\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}`? I think we should do the contrary: change from `standalone` to `IEEEtran` or so.

Comment: @JouleV since I want to use the same table in IEEE access class `\documentclass{ieeeaccess}` but I got many errors. And I googled the problem, it needs a lot of time to be fixed. So, I want to make it in standalone so I can get the output table as a pdf and just use it in my access document.

Comment: Then here is my suggestion: remove all Ti*k*Z-related stuff here, you don't need Ti*k*Z here. And the problem will be easier to solve. Could you please add a code using `ieeeaccess` (which returns errors)?

Comment: @JouleV I edited it.  I do not why tikz is not working with `ieeeaccess`. There is worka around to solve the problem but  when I tried, the first page does not show up.  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/440422/tikz-package-causing-error-in-ieee-access-template

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91262/156344. Btw, I don't think Ti*k*Z helps here - it is completely useless.

Comment: So, what do u recommend to have 3 tables beside each other. and an right arrow between each two of them

Comment: Oh you need the arrows, which you did not tell me :) Alright, Ti*k*Z is now necessary.

Comment: This is why I struggled to use use tikz with `ieeeaccess`. u can test using this template for IEEE access on overleaf. https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/ieee-access-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change your code to a `standalone` code.

> #### Warnings:
>
> 1. Table numbering no longer works (or I can't find a way to make it work).
>
>    - You may fix it manually by adding the PDF file in your main document, and then increase `table` counter.
> 2. You have to manually add captions. Use normal Ti*k*Z commands for this.
> 3. Labels no longer works (or I can't find a way to make it work).
> 4. You can no longer use `\hfill`. You have to adjust the spacing between tables manually.
>      Therefore, use it at your own risk!

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} % add margin=3.14mm if you like, but that will produce
                                 % a white space as margin, which should be avoid in
                                 % this particular case
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (tb1) {%Content
\begin{tabular}{cCc}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Start} & \makecell{\textbf{Interval}\\ \textbf{Time}} & \textbf{Disease} \\
    \midrule
    A & 483 & B \\
    A & 848 & C  \\
    A & 121 & Zone 4  \\
    B & 13 & C \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}};
\node[above=1ex,font=\scshape,align=center] at (tb1.north) {TABLE I\\First Table};
\node[right=4cm of tb1] (tb2) {%Content
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Start} & \makecell{\textbf{Interval}\\ \textbf{Time}} & \textbf{Disease} \\
    \midrule
    A & 483 & B \\
    A & 848 & C  \\
    A & 121 & Zone 4  \\
    B & 13 & C \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}};
\node[above=1ex,font=\scshape,align=center] at (tb2.north) {TABLE II\\Second Table};
\node[right=4cm of tb2] (tb3) {%Content
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Start} & \makecell{\textbf{Interval}\\ \textbf{Time}} & \textbf{Disease} \\
    \midrule
    A & 483 & B \\
    A & 848 & C  \\
    A & 121 & Zone 4  \\
    . & . & . \\
    . & . & .  \\
    B & 13 & C \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}};
\draw[-latex] (tb1) edge (tb2) (tb2) edge (tb3);
\node[above=1ex,font=\scshape,align=center] at (tb3.north) {TABLE III\\Third Table};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh greet. How to add captions to each table.

Comment: @HebaMohsen I added some captions.